# Opensource CANopen stacks: CANfestival vs CANopenNode

Tags: microcontroller

I'm looking for a CANopen stack to implement on a STM32F091RC (Nucleo) running MBED OS. 
I found two "popular" opensource stacks: [CANFestival](https://canfestival.org/code) and [CANopenNode](https://github.com/CANopenNode/CANopenNode/).

Does anyone have experience with one of them or another stack they were able to implement?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would throw [Lely CANOpen](https://opensource.lely.com/canopen/) in the mix, that's another serious, good quality candidate.
[Here are 2019 slides from a European Space Agency team comparing those three libs](https://indico.esa.int/event/276/contributions/4539/attachments/3500/4630/W43_-_Karl_-_cis19.pdf). See slide 6 in particular for a summary.

Note that since then the CANOpenNode license seems to have been updated : it's now Apache2